# Perl Script not working on Mac

Tags: perl, file-copying, network-share

I wrote a script in Perl to move images to a network share drive which works fine on a PC. When I try to run it on a Mac all I get are error messages. I can't figure out what is causing the problem. Would there be a reason the script won't run on the Mac? I'm using File::Copy and File::Find to move these files.

This is the error message I am getting:

copy failed:No such file or directory at "location of the script" line 14.

Any help would be great. Thanks. : )

```
 use File::Copy;
 use File::Find;
 my @source = qw (source/location);
 my $target   = q{//share/drive/location};

 while (1)
 { sleep (10);
   find(
    sub {
     if (-f) {
       print "$File::Find::name -> $target";
       copy($File::Find::name, $target)
       or die(q{copy failed:} . $!);

       }
        },
     @source
   ); 

  }
```

Comment: I assume "location of the script" is something you changed when copying the message and it actually said something like `/path/to/your/script`?

Comment: I've addded the script. If I try to use the code to copy between two folders I've placed on the Mac's desktop the code works perfectly. It's just when I try to copy the code to a share drive location it doesn't work. When I run this script on my PC it will copy to the share drive just not on the Mac.

Comment: Have you confirmed the source and target paths are visible to perl?

Comment: I know that the source path is visible. I'm not sure about the target path. I'm not sure if the way I wrote the path is the correct way to write it with the Mac and Perl? Would it be any different? I know that computer folders are represented a little bit differently on a Mac.  I can gain access to the target drive on the Mac.

Comment: Has that shared location been mapped to your Mac via SMB.  Like mentioned [here](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT4829) ?  It would then be mounted locally and be accessed via a path like `/mnt/some/location`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `//share/drive/location` is not valid on your Mac.  That is why you get the  `no such file or directory` message.

You can test this in a terminal window by trying to `cd` to that path.

That location will need to be mounted on your Mac so that you have a valid path to it.

That is done in your [Finder](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/21600/mount-a-windows-share-in-os-x-and-have-it-reconnect-at-login/) or via the [mount_smbfs](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT4829) command if you have a newer version of OSX.

Once that is done, you will have a path you can write to, such as `/mnt/some/path`.

Comment: Thank you. : ) That helps. I don't have much experience with using macs.

Answer (score 3):

You didn't supply any code, so I have to guess, but I'd say the file you're copying or the directory your copying to doesn't exist.

You probably have code like this on line 14.

```
copy($src, $dest) or die "copy failed:$!";
```

It would help you debug the program if you put `$src` and `$dest` into the error message.

```
copy($src, $dest) or die "copying $src to $dest failed: $!";
```

Answer (score -1):

Seems like the error explains it all:

```
copy failed:No such file or directory at "location of the script" line 14.
```

Is "location of the script" an uncommented comment? It seems like your Perl parser is trying parse a value or variable dubbed "location of the script"